# "Periodic Table" of Particles of the Standard Model?

Tags: standard-model, particle-physics

What is a good, single, "periodic table" of all the particles of the [Standard Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)?

I thought [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) would have a single-page PDF of this, but I couldn't find a single table listing all the particles.

Comment: What about [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=particles+of+standard+model&client=firefox-a&hs=k13&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=82FlU--zN8OrPL7agbgK&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1083&bih=691&gws_rd=cr)?

Comment: @Hunter: There seems to be quite a variety in the presentations. Is [this](http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/manitop/StandardModel/pics/standard_model_elementary_particles.png) the "standard" one?

Comment: @Geremia Your table is out of date. It has 17 particles now. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg

Comment: @DavidH: Thanks. What do the three encircled regions (that do not include the Higgs boson) mean?

Comment: @Geremia The inner circle is the set of particles that interact with gluons (strong force), the middle circle is the set of particles that interact with photons (electromagnetic force), and the outer circle is set of particles that interact with W's and Z's (weak force). We know some of the particles the Higgs interacts with but we're not sure if there are more or not so no circle as of yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The list doesn't really fit on one page:

[Baryon Table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/tables/rpp2013-qtab-baryons.pdf)

[Meson Table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/tables/rpp2013-qtab-mesons.pdf)

Then there are Gauge and Higgs bosons, Leptons and Quarks

Or do you just want fundamental particles?

Edit:

I like this one, although it isn't complete (all credit to Sean Carroll, [link to image](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/files/2012/04/WhatParticle3.png)):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Usually you see something like this for the fermions:
$$
\begin{array}{rccc} \text{Quarks: } &
u \choose d
&
c \choose s
& 
t \choose b
\\
\text{Leptons: } &
e \choose \nu_e
&
\mu \choose \nu_\mu
&
\tau \choose \nu_\tau
\end{array}
$$
Sometimes the four gauge bosons ($\gamma$, $W^±$, $Z^0$, $g$) will be listed along the side, making a 4×4 block of particles.  I find that misleading: there's nothing special about the photon (or any of the others) that should put it in the same row as the quarks with charge +2/3.

For more details, the [Contemporary Physics Education Project](http://www.cpepphysics.org/) has some nice posters, like this one:

[image: fundamental particles poster]

For composite states, like the different $\pi$ and $\rho$ mesons, the nucleons and delta baryons, etc., the Particle Data Group maintains a large database of particles.  There are a few sets of composite particles where an additional symmetry permits arranging the particles by common properties, such as the [baryon decuplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_decuplet).  But in chemistry you don't find any periodic table of *molecules*; for the most part in physics the repeating properties of composite particles are just as messy.