# Is mass a hash function?

Tags: quantum-information, mass

In what sense is mass a hash function?

Classically, it appears names can be avoided and replaced by numeric values in order to cut down on complexity. For instance, if I am running a grocery store, rather than storing the names of all the packaged products in a database, and putting bar codes or other unique identifiers on any of the packages, I could simply keep a high precision scale at all of the registers. Then, as long as the precision is high enough (say picograms), I can just use the mass of each packaged food item to quickly identify it.

Of course you could do the same thing for a set of particles in a physics model. For instance, if one wanted to put the Standard Model on a floppy disk, and needed to save a few bytes, rather than putting the names “electron neutrino”, “muon neutrino”, and “tau” neutrino, one might instead just use their masses in eV to identify them (why use English anyways?).

I’m wondering if there is a precise sense in which this analogy maps onto a physics model, say in the AdS/CFT correspondence. Like, if particles on the boundary are defined in terms of entangled qubit states, perhaps there is a (I hesitate to use the word quantum but a quantum) analog of a hash function that would allow the model to pick out and label particular particles in the model. References appreciated if the question is too vague.

Comment: Is all of this just a complicated way of asking: 1) does mass uniquely identify a particle in the SM? (and if so, why), 2) does this happen in some holographic models?

Comment: More or less, yes. However, as I never really experience a neutrino or a quark (I only experience the data my eyes and ears receive), I’m trying to pin down how to think of mass. Like, if the model is completely coded up in software, what would “mass” look like. Of course it may be just a list of hard-coded floats, but suggestively (this is a speculative idea, yes, don’t freak out) if the particles are data structures, then it may simplify the code to just write mass as something that serializes that data structure. Is there a Git repo where I can look at the SM?

Comment: The “development repository” is maintained by the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov); every couple of years there is a “release” which is a special journal issue running about 2000 printed pages. The short version fits on a poster; see the link in my answer.

Comment: Very cool! I hadn’t heard of that. I only once received the little book they used to send out . Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a good “hash function,” unique inputs map to unique outputs. However, even among the twenty-ish fundamental particles on the [Standard Model poster](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111103/44126), there are already several “hash collisions” with the same mass:

- the photon’s mass is zero
- the gluon’s mass is zero
- the graviton’s mass is zero

“Oh, those don’t count, those are force-carrying particles,” you say. However, while we have in the 21st century discovered that all three neutrino species have *different* masses, we have *not* ruled out that one neutrino species still has mass zero.

“Which neutrino species might have mass zero?” you ask, editing your table. Answer: the lightest neutrino is a mixture of the electron, muon, and tau neutrino flavor states. It’s either the one with the most electron neutrino, or the one with the least electron neutrino, depending on the [hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_mass_hierarchy).  The electron neutrino being emitted by your banana does not have a mass. That’s different from “the electron neutrino is massless”: the correct statement is that the electron neutrino is a coherent superposition of three particles which have different masses.

We can break the degeneracy among the massless force-carrying particles by noting that, in a superconducting material, the photon acquires an *effective* mass. This means that, within a superconductor, electromagnetism is a short-range rather than long-range interaction, and is related to the expulsion of magnetic fields. Unfortunately for the hash-table approach, the effective mass of a photon in a superconductor depends on the material’s composition, temperature, and other properties.

For that matter, the color force mediated by gluons is *also* subject to medium modifications.  But here the medium modifications go the other way.  The gluon is massless only in the interior of a proton, neutron, or other hadron. In the vacuum, the gluon acquires an effective mass and the color force becomes a short-range force. Our vacuum is a color superconductor.

The matter particles are subject to medium modifications, too.  In some perfect-crystal semiconductors, it’s awkward and complicated to describe charge transport in terms of electrons hopping from nucleus to nucleus. It’s more parsimonious to identify the quantized properties of the collective motion of the electron ocean as “quasiparticles” whose effective mass is typically comparable to, but different from, the electron mass. If these quasiparticles have negative charge we sometimes still call them “electrons” (or perhaps “dressed electrons”). If they have positive charge, we call them “holes.” In a material with both positive and negative charge carriers, the holes and the dressed electrons act a little like particles and antiparticles, forming in oppositely-charged pairs and annihilating each other if they get too close.  The effective masses of electrons and holes are usually *not* the same, unlike particles and antiparticles. You can explain this away because a semiconductor crystal has a large matter excess over antimatter, so it’s reasonable to expect that matter and antimatter should behave differently in that environment.

But of course, our vacuum *also* has $\mathit{CP}$ violation: matter and antimatter behave differently enough that the visible part of our universe is made entirely of matter, with only incidental antimatter.  It’s surprisingly hard to rule out the idea that our vacuum is a “false vacuum” and that our particles are quasiparticle excitations in the “true vacuum.” Like a fish who never understands he is in water, perhaps we cannot see that our universe’s “real matter” is hiding the dark sector.

And there’s another medium effect (or lack-of-medium effect) in QCD: the light quarks, for whom confinement is the strongest, have very weak constraints on their masses.  The “dressed quark masses” are around $\rm \frac13\,GeV$, because nucleons are made of three valence quarks. However, the “bare quark” masses are much closer to $\rm2\,MeV$.

Your idea of mass as a hash function only really works for the easy cases.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using masses as a substitute for the names overlooks the real meaning of names of elementary particles and doesn't work.

It doesn't work because, at the best of our theoretical and experimental understanding, particles and anti-particles have the same mass. Therefore a mass equal to $9.10938~10^{-31}$ kg wouldn't tell us anything about the electric charge.

Moreover, using masses in the place of names by no means cuts complexity (using the symbol $e^-$ really uses fewer bytes than $9.10938~10^{-31}$)  and overlooks the simple fact that names are already a kind of hash function mapping the full set of properties (mass, charge, spin, magnetic moment etc.) into a string set.

Comment: When I say save complexity, I’m thinking not so much as a way to save bytes from “tau neutrino” to “xx…xx eV”, but rather as a way to avoid hard-coding 17 numeric values. The length of a function “mass” which acts on the particle objects in the theory might be shorter that the 17 parameters. What is the real meaning of the names of elementary particles?

Answer (score 0):

A successful theme in physics, has been the identification of elementary particles (in fact all objects!) with kets in the carrier space of irreducible representations of Lie Groups. It takes lots of parameters (eg: $J,J_z,Q,I_{weak},\vec{P}.E,M,......$ to mathematically label the kets.  You suggest there might be a way (a hash function) to combine this set of labels into one number (mass).  I have never seen a mathematical way of labelling the IRs and kets of Lie Groups with one number except for the trivial case of U(1). In general, labelling takes an array of numbers (eg: Gelfand Pattern for GL(N) which is just writing down the max weight vectors for a sequence of subgroups).  Perhaps there is some mathematical theorem addressing if the many labels can be reduced to one? ... I guess they can't, just like identifying a point (x,y,z) in our 3-vector space can't be reduced to one number.

Answer (score 0):

Mass gets renormalised. If there is a unified theory of the forces then it is likely that several particles have the same mass as the unification scale. This is e.g. the case in the mSUGRA model.

Comment: Sounds like a wicked hash collision, to be technical. At the level of thinking where mass renormalization means “it changes with scale”, in this “view the standard model as a software engineering problem & think about the data structures and algorithms that would appear & how to properly structure the code” analogy, mass would be something like the Kolmogorov complexity of a data structure corresponding to a particle. The first thing that comes to mind as analogous to renormalization would be compression algorithms. Compressing the data structure & taking its length would give different mass.